# I am facing problems while calling recursive function in merge sort in C Language

Tags: c, recursion, mergesort

I basically want to implement merge sort without creating an extra array. But when I call my function recursively gcc gives segmentation fault error
Here is my code

**Right Circular Shift**

```
void rightCircularShift(int *a, int startPos, int endPos)
{
    int temp, j;
    temp = a[endPos - 1];
    for (j = endPos - 1; j > startPos; j--) {
        a[j] = a[j - 1];
    }
    a[startPos] = temp;
}
```

**Merge**

```
void merge(int *a, int l, int r, int m)
{
    int leftCounter = l, elementsMoved = 0;
    int rightCounter = m;
    while (elementsMoved < r) {
        if (leftCounter != r || rightCounter != r) {
            if (a[leftCounter] < a[rightCounter]) {
                leftCounter++;
            } else {
                rightCircularShift(a, leftCounter, rightCounter + 1);
                leftCounter++;
                rightCounter++;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
        elementsMoved++;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, *array;
    system("clear");
    printf("\nEnter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    printf("Enter value of elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    mergeSort(array, 0, n - 1);
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Merge Sort**

```
void mergeSort(int *a, int left, int right)
{
    int mid = (left + right + 1) / 2;
    if (left < right) { 
        mergeSort(a, left, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid + 1, right);
        merge(a, left, right, mid);
    }   
}
```

I have ensured the rest of the functions like circular shift and merge are working properly with test cases, but I get this error:

[image: Error]

Comment: "gcc gives segmentation" - the *compiler* seg-faults ? That ain't good. Pretty sure it's your *program* that is faulting, which you can debug *very* quickly by running it with another tool in your toolbox: your **debugger** (ex: gdb). It will halt your program on the fault and allow you to examine variables and call stack state in detail.

Comment: Have you stepped through it in a debugger to find the exact location of the problem?

Comment: `if(leftCounter != r || rightCounter != r)` You probably want `&&` there.

Comment: The `merge` function doesn't make sense.  Specifically, the circular shifting.  Regardless of the correctness, that circular shift completely destroys the performance.  The whole point of doing a merge sort is that it runs in O(n*log(n)) time.  This implementation won't.  I understand that the circular shift allows the merge to be done in place, but at a performance cost that destroys the benefit of doing a merge sort.  A simple-minded O(n^2) bubble sort would be faster than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in the `mergeSort` function: you compute the `mid` index incorrectly, for a slice of 2 elements, `mid` will be equal to `right` and the call `mergeSort(a, mid + 1, right)` will have undefined behavior because `mid + 1 > right`, a condition the function cannot handle.

You should use `int mid = (left + right) / 2;` or better:

```
    int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;  // prevent potential overflow
```

There is also a problem in the `merge` function: the test `elementsMoved < r` is incorrect as `r` is the index of the last element and `elementsMoved` the number of iterations. It does not make sense to iterate more than `r - l + 1` times, but the test does not implement that.

You use 2 different conventions in your code:

- `endPos` is the index past the end of the slice in `void rightCircularShift(int *a, int startPos, int endPos)`
- `right` is the index of the last element of the slice in `void mergeSort(int *a, int left, int right)`

It would be less confusing to always use the first convention, which is customary in C, where array indexes start at `0`.

Also not that you must use `<=` in `if (a[leftCounter] <= a[rightCounter])` to make the sort stable.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rightCircularShift(int *a, int startPos, int endPos) {
    if (startPos < endPos) {
        int temp = a[endPos - 1];
        for (int j = endPos - 1; j > startPos; j--) {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        }
        a[startPos] = temp;
    }
}

void merge(int *a, int left, int mid, int right) {
    int leftCounter = left;
    int rightCounter = mid;
    while (leftCounter < mid && rightCounter < right) {
        if (a[leftCounter] <= a[rightCounter]) {
            leftCounter++;
        } else {
            rightCircularShift(a, leftCounter, rightCounter + 1);
            leftCounter++;
            rightCounter++;
            mid++;
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int left, int right) {
    if (right - left > 1) {
        // mid is the index of the first element of the second slice
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, left, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid, right);
        merge(a, left, mid, right);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, i, *array;
    system("clear");
    printf("\nEnter number of elements: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0)
        return 1;
    array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * n);
    if (array == NULL)
        return 1;
    printf("Enter value of elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    mergeSort(array, 0, n);
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that implementing merge sort this way is very inefficient: the space needed is limited to **O(log(N))**, corresponding to the recursion depth, but the average time complexity explodes to **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** or worse, especially for the very example tested: an array sorted in decreasing order.

There are ways to implement merge sort with limited amount of memory while limiting this downside, but they are more complicated than this simple approach.

Comment: Thanks I actually know it is very inefficient to implement merge sort this way it has O(n2logn) time complexity but I was told to do it in this particular way